# Errors on shell infile

Tags: shell

I got a text file test.txt

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

and a shell script

```
filename="test.txt"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    if [ "$line" = "a" ]  
        then
        echo "abc"
    fi

done < "$filename"
```

I expect to see a line "abc" after "a"
However what I got is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: It works for me.  Do you have an invisible character (whitespace) after the `a` on the first line of test.txt?

Comment: seems no as I try for all a,b,c,d,e and none of them work

Comment: I found that there is a ^M 
Thank you for your help.